# Implementar Mapa Globo Rajawali en un fragment Andriod

Tags: android

Buenos días, tengo problemas con incorporar el mapa tierra en un  fragment android
Desde una actividad se realiza de esta manera:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RajawaliSurfaceView surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(this);
    surface.setFrameRate(60.0);
    surface.setRenderMode(IRajawaliSurface.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

    // Add mSurface to your root view
    addContentView(surface, new  ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    surface.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
}
```

Pero  cuando quiero hacerlo dentro de un fragment me da error la línea

```
addContentView(surface, new  ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Error:(81, 9) error: cannot find symbol method addContentView(RajawaliSurfaceView,LayoutParams)

Comment: Hola Mauricio, bienvenido a "StackOverflow en Español", imagino tienes un NullPointerException verdad? siempre trata de agregar mensajes de error desplegados en el LogCat, eso es demasiado importante para diagnosticar el problema.

Comment: Mauricio la documentación es un poco incorrecta en algunos puntos, no se puede cargar el Mapa con el mismo código dentro de una Actividad o un Fragmento, ve mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Existe un problema al diferenciar Fragmento y Actividad, este mensaje de error:

> cannot find symbol method addContentView()

indica que este método no existe.

Además la [documentación](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Using-RajawaliSurfaceView-and-RajawaliTextureView) es incorrecta, no puedes cargar el mapa desde un fragmento con (this) :

```
final RajawaliSurfaceView surface = new RajawaliSurfaceView(this);
```

Este es un ejemplo basico de **Como cargar el mapa Rajawali3D  dentro de un Fragmento**

[image]

Crea la Actividad, agregando la transacción del Fragmento, el Fragmento es cargado dentro del contenedor `map_fragment`, definido en el layout `act_frag_map`:

```
public class Map3DFragActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RajawaliSurfaceView rajawaliTexture;
    Renderer renderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_frag_map);

        setFragment();

    }

    protected void setFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment mapFragment = new FragmentMap();
        FragmentTransaction ft =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.map_fragment, mapFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Este es el layout que contiene un fragmento, se agrega en la propiedad `android:name` el nombre de nuestra clase fragmento:

**act_frag_map**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentExampleActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.FragmentMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Este es el Fragmento que crea el Mapa:

**FragmentMap**

```
import org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView;

public class FragmentMap extends Fragment {

    public RajawaliSurfaceView rajawaliTexture;
    Renderer renderer;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag_map,
                container, false);

        rajawaliTexture = (RajawaliSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.rajawali_surface);
        renderer = new Renderer(getActivity());
        rajawaliTexture.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // make sure this line exists

    }
}
```

**activity_frag_map**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:surfaceview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <org.rajawali3d.surface.RajawaliSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/rajawali_surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        surfaceview:frameRate="60.0"
        surfaceview:renderMode="RENDER_WHEN_DIRTY"/>

</FrameLayout>
```